Visual Studio custom refactorings
I would like to create a refactor or template in Visual Studio 2022 to wrap some code easily with my custom code. For example if I have the function like this
void MyFunc() 
{
  DoSomething();
}

I would like to be able to select the DoSomething(), click refactor and then it converts it to.
void MyFunc()
{
  try
  {
    DoSomething();
  } catch {
    // Handle error
  }
}

Is there an easy way to setup a template like this?

I found I can create a code snippet and import it. The snippet I created is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>Surround with Try/Catch</Title>
      <Shortcut>shortcutsdontwork</Shortcut>
      <Description>        
      </Description>
      <Author></Author>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="CSharp">
        <![CDATA[  try
  {
    $selected$
  } catch {
    // Handle error
  }$end$]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>

